# Github Actions for dbt project

Tags: docker, dockerfile, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to setup Github Actions for a dbt project. This is how my workflow yml looks like:

```
name: Build and Push Docker Image to Google Cloud Artifact Registry

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature_branch_1

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check Out Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

    - name: Login to Google Cloud Registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev
        username: _json_key
        password: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_SECRET }}

    - name: Build and push Docker image
      run: |
          docker build -t gcr.io/project_name/image_name:$GITHUB_SHA .
          echo ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_SECRET }} | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
          docker push gcr.io/project_name/image_name:$GITHUB_SHA
```

and this is how my Dockerfile looks:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster

WORKDIR /home

COPY . /home

# Install dbt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir dbt-bigquery

# Run dbt when the container launches
RUN dbt deps && dbt source snapshot-freshness
```

The pipeline fails at step "Build and push Docker Image" Step 5/5: RUN dbt deps && dbt source snapshot-freshness with the error:
"Runtime Error
No dbt_project.yml found at expected path /home/dbt_project.yml"

I am not an expert on CI/CD topics, when I start a Docker Container locally I usually "enter" it and check in which directory my code is, but I dont know how to do this when using GitHub Actions. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there conflicting information in the yml and the Dockerfile itself?
Thanks!

Update: I had to adapt my Dockerfile and write "COPY dbt .", because this is the subfolder where the actual dbt code is located

Comment: do you have a `dbt_project.yml` file in your git repo? Can you try to give an explicit path using `dbt deps --packages /home/dbt_project.yml` and see if that helps?

Comment: Hi Faizan, thanks for the reply. When I run dbt deps --packages /home/dbt_project.yml, I get the error: Error: No such option: --packages

Comment: ok, so I tried --project-dir instead, but I get the error that the path does not exist. So it appears the part where I want to copy the code does not work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it:
I had to adapt my Dockerfile and write "COPY dbt .", because this is the subfolder where the actual dbt code is located